# Can't load a static file on Android 2.1

Tags: java, android

I need to load a `text` file which is placed in `res/raw` directory into memory. Here is my code:

```
package com.ggd543.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class FileActivity extends Activity {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        loadText();
    }

    private void loadText() {
//        InputStream is = Resources.getSystem().openRawResource(R.raw.text);
        InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.text);
        try {
            byte[] buf = new byte[is.available()];
            is.read(buf, 0, buf.length);
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.layout.main)).setText(new String(buf, "UTF-8"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
    }
}
```

}

When I deploy the `.apk` on emulator and start it up, I got the following error:

```
12-25 14:33:38.096: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3077): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
12-25 14:33:38.106: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3077): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ggd543.android/com.ggd543.android.FileActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030000
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030000
        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:891)
        at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResource(Resources.java:816)
        at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResource(Resources.java:798)
        at com.ggd543.android.FileActivity.loadText(FileActivity.java:23)
        at com.ggd543.android.FileActivity.onCreate(FileActivity.java:19)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
        ... 11 more
```

Could anyone give me suggestion  ?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the file to the assets folder.

Then retrieve the stream like this `InputStream is = getAssets().open("fileName");`

if you have assets/mytxtfile.txt
then fileName = "mytxtfile.txt"

Comment: It works, but why can't android system find it in `res/raw` directory

Comment: @爱国者 Try adding package name : `getResources().openRawResource(com.YourProject.R.raw.text);`

Answer (score 1):

What is the file name ? coz as per odcs, if you've a file called 'abcd.txt' in /res/raw, you're suppose to open it using resource ID "R.raw.abcd", i.e. excluding the 3 digit extension.

Comment: my filename is `text` placing in `res/raw` directory

Comment: Can you rename your file to have an extension, say 'text.txt' or something like that, and try again ?

Comment: it's strange that both `text` and `text.txt` placing in `res/raw` directory works when I woke up this morning